# Memory usage of my process

Tags: c, linux, memory-management

I have an application written in C. I am trying to analyse its memory usage. See how the used memory grows over time and check different usage patterns for it. I've been using top command to check for VM and RSS but recently got to know they do not give the exact picture of what is happening. Also tried using pmap but not able to play around much with the output. Can someone help me find some good memory profiling tools? I am basically looking for a clear picture of how much memory my process is using, whether any kind of fragmentation occurs? Also some help with the pmap would be appreciated.

Comment: You might want to check out [Valgrind](http://www.valgrind.org/) and its [tools](http://www.valgrind.org/info/tools.html).

Comment: Valgrind is good for malloc usage, though you can also use sbrk(0) to find the total heap allocation. For stack usage, you can compare the stack pointer to the stack pointer for main (or find the base of the stack, which I don't know off the top of my head).

Comment: I tried exploring "massif". The output looks a little complicated but I guess it would have quite good information.